# Loading data in separate thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I load resources in separate thread, for it I use lockfree queue (https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue) In main thread I add item to queue. In loading thread I have loop where I dequeue pointer and load data.

```
while (loading_queue_.try_dequeue(ptr))
{
    async_load(prt)
}
```

then I add item to another lockfree queue to be processed in main thread

```
void AsyncLoader::async_load(Data* data)
{
    loader_->load_thread_a(data);
    update_queue_.emplace(data); // can this code be executed before line above finishes?
}
```

In main thead I dequeue item add finish loading

```
load_main_thread()
{
    Data* data;
    if (update_queue_.try_dequeue(data))
    {
        loader_->load_main_thead(data);
        data->load_state = Loaded;
    }
}
```

Is it possible that update_queue_.emplace(data); happens before load_thread_a, due to compiler reordering instructions or out of order execution?
Should I use some kind of synchronization to prevent it?

Comment: what is `load_thread_a`?

Comment: it does some job for data, mainly initialization or precomputing depends on data type. it's just function that is called in loading thread

Comment: so there is **no** thread involve in that function? then you do not need synchronization.

Comment: no, there is only two thread loading thread from witch loading is called and main thread from wich load_main_thread is called

Comment: For a start, it would help if you provided a [mcve]. Asking yes/no questions about potential code is just not a fruitful approach. Also, I guess something doesn't work as expected, and with threads, there are multiple ways in parallel to screw up, but you don't even describe a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It’s absolutely possible, If your queue implementation is faulty. But if the queue was properly implemented, it will use the proper atomic operations to prevent the compiler and the processor from making the loaded object visible before the loading is actually complete.